# Handling classes that violate the 'Liskov substitution principle' using method overloading

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass {

    /* Note: Timestamp extends date */
    public doSomething(java.sql.Timestamp timestamp){
        System.out.println("Timestamp");
        ...
    }

    public doSomething(java.util.Date date){
        System.out.println("Date");
        ...
    }
}
```

Suppose that I now exercise my code like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

Date realDate = new Date();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(0);
Date casted = new Timestamp(0);

myClass.doSomething(realDate);      // prints Date
myClass.doSomething(timestamp);     // prints Timestamp
myClass.doSomething(casted);        // prints Date!!!!!  What?!
```

The problem that I am having is that since `casted` is not actually a date, when I use it doesn't work.

*Aside: Generally, subclasses not working shouldn't be an issue, however the javadoc for Timestamp says:*

> Due to the differences between the Timestamp class and the java.util.Date class mentioned above, it is recommended that code not view Timestamp values generically as an instance of java.util.Date. The inheritance relationship between Timestamp and java.util.Date really denotes implementation inheritance, and not type inheritance.

I know that I could do something like this:

```
public doSomething(java.util.Date date){
    if(date instanceof type){
        System.out.println("Timestamp");
        ...
    }
    System.out.println("Date");
    ...
}
```

But this just seems nasty.

Is there a way to get method overloading of subclasses to work without using giant switch statements?

---

*Edit*: In short, it seems like `Timestamp` breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - as pointed out by [@Mick Mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905488/mick-mnemonic).

Comment: This _is_ how method overloading works correctly.  Method overloads are chosen at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: (Additionally, it's generally considered a serious design smell for `foo(subtype)` to behave differently from `foo(supertype)`, for precisely this reason.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman - I don't think that is **my** design flaw though.  I think that the autor of timestamp is the flaw-author.  Is that your read as well?

Comment: That's pretty much what the documentation you quoted says, yes -- that you should never assign a `Timestamp` to a `Date`.

Comment: In short, `Timestamp` (and also `java.sql.Date`) breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @MickMnemonic - Thanks for the link.  I have incorporated your comment into the question.

Comment: One solution is to write wrappers for the standard classes with correct inheritance and then use those. I don't say it will be prettier than the if else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Not your bug. It's a design quirk of `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, and `Timestamp`. (Don't be too hard on them. `java.util.Date` is twenty years old now; they were still figuring this stuff out when they were designing the API.) There's no great way around it if you work directly with these types.

One approach is to avoid using these classes except where you have to, at the boundary with APIs that require them, and use a better-designed set of date-time types elsewhere. In your data access layer, special-case `Timestamp` etc using `instanceof` where necessary. And convert everything to Joda-Time (for Java 7) or `java.time`/JSR-310 (for Java 8) types for your internal code. (If you actually need nanosecond precision in Java 7, you'll need to roll your own Timestamp object to go with the Joda-Time types. Not hard; just make sure to use composition instead of implementation inheritance like the `java.util` folks did! :) ) You will probably be happier.